# Unable to call WCF Restful service from jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

Following is my code from jQuery script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
              cache: false,
              type: "GET",
              async: true,                  
              dataType: "json",
              url: "http://localhost:9002/SampleServices/Service/REST/Employees",                  
              processdata: false,                  
              error: ServiceFailed,
              success: function () { alert("succeeded");   }
          });
      });

      function ServiceFailed(result) {
          alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
          Type = null;
          Url = null;
          Data = null;
          ContentType = null;
          DataType = null;
          ProcessData = null;
      }

      function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
          alert("error");
          alert(xhr.responseText);
          if (xhr.responseText) {
              var err = xhr.responseText;
              if (err)
                  error(err);
              else
                  error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
          }
          return;
      }
```

When I run the above code it always enters ServiceFailed(xhr) and alerts "error".

When I try to execute the above url ("http://localhost:9002/SampleServices/Service/REST/Employees") through the browser I get following JSON response: 
{"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"cell":["1","Haris","21-03-1979","HR"],"id":1}],"total":1}

Fiddler says following when I run the jQuery script:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
1   200 HTTP    localhost:9002  /SampleServices/Service/REST/Employees?_=1340833203960  89      application/json; charset=utf-8 chrome:1448
```

Comment: Is the request coming from a different domain than the service? If so, you're hitting a cross-domain request issue.

Comment: you have two definitions for `ServiceFailed`. That's not right.  Javascript is dynamically typed, so there's no way for the runtime to distinguish between those definitions.  It may be that you are imagining Javascript will call a different `ServiceFailed` based on the type and number of input params you provide, as in C# or Java. This is not what happens in Javascript. Also: normally Javascript functions get a lowercase or camelCase name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

carlosfigueira nailed it.

This was a cross domain request hence i needed to add crossdomain support in App.config file for my WCF service

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the error callback function accepts three parameters: `jqXHR`, `textStatus`, and `errorThrown`.

Your method only has one parameter.  You should start by having your error method take three parameters and inspect what values they have.